# Construct bivariate symmetric (polynomial) nonnegative functions (distributions) over the unit square with certain properties

Tags: integration, polynomials, probability-distributions, quantum-mechanics, bivariate-distributions

Construct bivariate symmetric polynomials $f(x,y) = f(y,x) \ge 0$ over $[0,1]^2$, with $f(1,y) = f(x,1)=0$,  such that the univariate marginal distributions are both proportional to

$$(1-u^2)^4$$, where $u$ is either $x$ or $y$

and the "diagonal" $f(x,x) = f(y,y)$ is proportional to

$$(1-u)^5$$

Also, the same form of problem with marginals

$$(1-u^2)^6$$

and diagonal

$$(1-u)^9 (1+8 u)$$

And a third case requiring the marginals

$$(1-u^2)^8$$

and diagonal

$$(1-u)^{11} (1+u (11+40 u))$$

These problems have a quantum-information-theoretic relevance pertaining to separability probability calculations.

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201369/2451

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, the following function has the right form and integrals:
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{4375}{256}(x^2-y^2)^4 -\frac{4119}{256}(x^4-y^4)^2 
+ \frac{6136937}{49600}(x^2-y^2)^2 \\
+ \frac{3607}{186}(x^6+y^6)-\frac{3607}{5952}(x+y)^6 
\\+\frac{1223}{620}(x^5+y^5) - \frac{1533}{9920}(x+y)^5
\\ + \frac{42781757}{2083200}(x+y)^4 
-\frac{42130757}{260400}(x^4+y^4)\\
+\frac{5646847}{520800}(x+y)^3 - \frac{6297847}{130200}(x^3+y^3) \\
+\frac{12576953}{208320}(x^2+y^2) - \frac{11715353}{416640}(x+y)^2
\\ -\frac52(x+y)+1
$$

The derivation is on the cross-posted question.

Unfortunately, I now see that the function is not non-negative on $[0,1]^2$ (although $f(x,x)$ is indeed non-negative). But the same technique as was used to derive this should allow forcing the function to stay positive.  But I was unable to perform the calculations, even with full Mathematica.

Comment: I referenced the physics crosspost (in the abstract and end) this interesting, diligent piece of analysis by Mark Fischer in my posting https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.06459.pdf which is in press at the Intl. J. Quantum Information. I hadn't seen the "Unfortunately,..." caveat at the time. Still an impressive endeavor.

Comment: Sorry for the Fisch(l)er misspelling--too late to edit.